# Custom AuthorizeAttribute with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am currently in the process of trying to migrate a .NET Framework 4.7 ASP MVC application over to .NET Core 3.1.  I am using ASP.NET Core and found when I did the conversion I had issues with some of the custom authorization filters I was using on my methods.  I want to retain the current attributes if possible, but I NEED access to the actual instance of the controller object - so I can set the value of an object inside that controller I can then access (for example, a User ID or other object) but I am unable to get the instance.

I want to decorate specific Actions with this attribute and when an incoming request comes through, perform some validation logic.

I've seen other code examples showing how via reflection I can get the controller name or type, but I need the ACTUAL INSTANCE not just the details of the object.  Hope this is clear, any help is appreciated.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext authorizationFilterContext)
    {
            //How can I access the Controller instance here
            //Not just the controller name, I need the actual instance
    }
}
```

Comment: look at authorizationFilterContext.ActionDescriptor, - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.actiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks, I just did and was not able to find any tangible way to extract the instance from ActionDescriptor, or it isn't documented well enough.

Comment: sorry, just re-red your post...why not use AuthenticationHandler if you're using .netcore?

Comment: Because I am trying to allow specific actions to be accessible only to users who have access, for example: [ValidateAccess(AccessType=Accounts)] would allow the users who are logged in to be validated against a specific type of access.

Comment: yes, - here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1